# 16.04 - /dev/ttyACM0 and /dev/ttyUSB0 do not exist

Tags: usb, mount, tty

I'm trying to connect an MSP430fr5969 on ttyACM0 - however, it doesn't look like this port exists. I've added the udev rules and added myself to the dialout group. Is there a way to create the missing serial port, or instruct the device to use a different port?

Output of `sudo lsusb -v` (only relevant port included):

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2047:0203 Texas Instruments 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x2047 Texas Instruments
  idProduct          0x0203 
  bcdDevice            1.05
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.01
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      36
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Output of `ls /dev/`:

```
.
..
autofs
block
bsg
btrfs-control
bus
cdrom
cdrw
char
console
core
cpu
cpu_dma_latency
cuse
disk
dri
drm_dp_aux0
drm_dp_aux1
dvd
dvdrw
ecryptfs
fb0
fb1
fd
freefall
full
fuse
hidraw0
hidraw1
hpet
hugepages
hwrng
i2c-0
i2c-1
i2c-10
i2c-11
i2c-12
i2c-13
i2c-14
i2c-15
i2c-16
i2c-17
i2c-18
i2c-19
i2c-2
i2c-3
i2c-4
i2c-5
i2c-6
i2c-7
i2c-8
i2c-9
initctl
input
kmsg
kvm
lightnvm
log
loop0
loop1
loop2
loop3
loop4
loop5
loop6
loop7
loop-control
mapper
mcelog
media0
mei0
mem
memory_bandwidth
mqueue
net
network_latency
network_throughput
null
port
ppp
psaux
ptmx
pts
random
rfkill
rtc
rtc0
sda
sda1
sda2
sda3
sdb
sdb1
sdb2
sdb5
sdb6
sdb7
sdb8
sg0
sg1
sg2
shm
snapshot
snd
sr0
stderr
stdin
stdout
tty
tty0
tty1
tty10
tty11
tty12
tty13
tty14
tty15
tty16
tty17
tty18
tty19
tty2
tty20
tty21
tty22
tty23
tty24
tty25
tty26
tty27
tty28
tty29
tty3
tty30
tty31
tty32
tty33
tty34
tty35
tty36
tty37
tty38
tty39
tty4
tty40
tty41
tty42
tty43
tty44
tty45
tty46
tty47
tty48
tty49
tty5
tty50
tty51
tty52
tty53
tty54
tty55
tty56
tty57
tty58
tty59
tty6
tty60
tty61
tty62
tty63
tty7
tty8
tty9
ttyprintk
ttyS0
ttyS1
ttyS10
ttyS11
ttyS12
ttyS13
ttyS14
ttyS15
ttyS16
ttyS17
ttyS18
ttyS19
ttyS2
ttyS20
ttyS21
ttyS22
ttyS23
ttyS24
ttyS25
ttyS26
ttyS27
ttyS28
ttyS29
ttyS3
ttyS30
ttyS31
ttyS4
ttyS5
ttyS6
ttyS7
ttyS8
ttyS9
uhid
uinput
urandom
usb
userio
v4l
vboxdrv
vboxdrvu
vboxnetctl
vboxusb
vcs
vcs1
vcs2
vcs3
vcs4
vcs5
vcs6
vcsa
vcsa1
vcsa2
vcsa3
vcsa4
vcsa5
vcsa6
vfio
vga_arbiter
vhci
vhost-net
video0
zero
```

Answer (score 1):

The ttyACM0 device comes from a CDC modem interface. Unless it's compiled in your kernel you probably wont see the ttyACM0 devices.

These are found in make menuconfig.

```
Device Drivers -->
  USB support -->
    USB Modem (CDC ACM) support
```

If there is still no ttyACM0 device, then there may be an additional kernel module required that is specific to that device.

You will need to apt-get install linux-headers before you can compile the kernel. The kernel source is located in /usr/src/linux.

```
make all 
make modules_install 
make install
```

If you are a software developer you may also need:

```
make headers_install
```

The installation of the kernel will depend on your boot loader, for me, i use grub, so for me it's:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Be sure to be change this device to your linux boot drive.